# Check if function is jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing an ajax queue and I want to ensure that the type of function (comes in an object) is in fact an ajax request so that .done/.fail/.always can be called on it. How can I do this?

Comment: Can include `js` at Question ?

Comment: Are you expecting values different from jQuery promises?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to ensure that the type of function (comes in an object) is in fact an ajax request so that .done/.fail/.always can be called on it.

jQuery ajax request objects (`jqXHR`) aren't functions. In jQuery v1.12.0 (the version I had handy to check), they're plain objects with properties added (e.g., no special constructor), so you can't use `instanceof` to see if they're `jqXHR` objects.

You can test whether `done`, `fail`, and/or `always` are present on the object you get:

```
if (obj.done && obj.fail && obj.always) {
    // It's probably a jqXHR
}
```

Or if you wanted to be more thorough you might make sure they were functions:

```
if (typeof obj.done == "function" &&
    typeof obj.fail == "function" &&
    typeof obj.always == "function") {
    // It's probably a jqXHR
}
```

This is an example of "duck typing": It quacks like a duck, so we'll assume it's a duck.

If you want to really limit it as much as you can to `jqXHR` objects and not other things that have those functions, you could check for other functions/properties that they have, such as `getAllResponseHeaders` and such.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this before:

```
if(data && $.isFunction(data.promise)) {
...
}
```

> I want to ensure that the type of function (comes in an object) is in
>   fact an ajax request so that .done/.fail/.always can be called on it.

From the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) documentation:

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).
>
> Available Promise methods of the jqXHR object include:
>
> **jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});** An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.
>
> **jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});** An
>   alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method
>   replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for
>   implementation details.
>
> **jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) {
>   });*** An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the
>   .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.

Related question/answers:

1. [Any way to check whether a variable is a real jqXHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587373/any-way-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-a-real-jqxhr)
2. [How can I tell if an object is a jQuery Promise/Deferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075985/37966)

Answer (score 1):

Checking if something is a promise, or in jQuery's case a Deferred, can be done by checking that the object is *"thenable"*, i.e. that it has a `then()` method

```
var xhr = $.ajax({url:'...'});

if (typeof xhr === 'object' && typeof xhr.then === 'function') ...
```

This would work with any promises (also A+), to specifically check for the `fail`, `done` and `always` methods that a jQuery ajax call always would have, see T.J's answer.

Comment: Object could have a `then` property though not be an `$.ajax()` request. _"I want to ensure that the type of function (comes in an object) is in fact an ajax request"_

Comment: If it has a `then` method in jQuery, it's a *"thenable"* Deferred/Promise, and it has the usual callbacks even if it isn't an ajax call.

Comment: `.done`, `.fail` and `.always` are part of the deferred api so it's not limited to ajax requests either.

Comment: Question appears to seek to determine if returned object is an `$.ajax()` request, not only having  `then`  property ? See OP at _"I want to ensure that the type of function (comes in an object) is in fact an ajax request"_

Comment: And if it's supposed to be limited to only ajax, one can do as noted by T.J. above, check for specific properties only ajax calls have, like `setRequestHeader` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for `status` property, calling `.state()` function

```
if (object.status && (obj.state() === "resolved" || obj.state() === "rejected")) {
      if (obj.status === 200) obj.done(success)
      else obj.fail(err)
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

---

alternatively, use [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), which should be called at completed `$.ajax()` requests

> All `ajaxComplete` handlers are invoked, regardless of what Ajax
>   request was completed. If you must differentiate between the requests,
>   use the parameters passed to the handler. Each time an `ajaxComplete`
>   handler is executed, it is passed the event object, the
>   `XMLHttpRequest` object, and the settings object that was used in the
>   creation of the request.

```
$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(event, xhr, settings) {
   // do stuff
})
```

Comment: @adeneo `// do other stuff` ; could use `$.when(obj).always()` at `else` statement for object that is neither explicitly fulfilled or rejected

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I think all those answers are pretty unsatisfying.
If someone in the future really wants to check if a passed object is a Promise try this function.

```
function isPromise (obj) {
    const normal = !!obj && typeof obj === 'object' &&
                   ((obj.constructor && obj.constructor.name === 'Promise') || typeof obj.then === 'function');

    const fnForm = !!obj  && (typeof obj === 'function') && 
                   ((obj.name === 'Promise') || (typeof obj.resolve === 'function') && (typeof obj.reject === 'function'));

    return normal || fnForm;
}
```

works with ES6 promises, Bluebird and jQuery ajax.